# Are there any licenses considered free by the OSI and not by the FSF and Vice Versa?

Tags: osi, fsf

Are there any licenses considered free by the OSI and not by the FSF and Vice Versa?

They both seem to further the same point, and all the licenses I saw they both agreed that it was either free or not.

Do they ever disagree?